# differentiation of a matrix function

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

In statistics, the residual sum of squares is given by the formula

$$ \operatorname{RSS}(\beta) = (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)^T(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)$$

I know differentiation of scalar functions, but how to I perform derivatives on this wrt $\beta$? By the way, I am trying to take the minimum of RSS wrt to $\beta$, so I am setting the derivative equal to 0.

---

I know somehow product rule has to hold. So here I have the first step

$$-\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta) + (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^T(-\mathbf{X})= 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can remove the transposition sign from the first bracket:

$RSS=(\mathbf{y}^T - \beta ^T \mathbf{X} ^T)(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)$

Multiplying out:

$RSS=y^Ty-\beta ^T \mathbf{X} ^Ty-y^TX\beta+\beta^TX^T X\beta $

$\beta ^T \mathbf{X} ^Ty$ and $y^TX\beta$ are equal. Thus

$RSS=y^Ty-2\beta ^T \mathbf{X} ^Ty+\beta^TX^T X\beta$

Now you can differentiate with respect to $\beta$:

$\frac{\partial RSS}{\partial \beta}=-2X^Ty+2X^T X\beta=0$

Dividing by 2 and bringing the first summand to the RHS:

$X^T X\beta=X^Ty$

Multiplying both sides by $(X^T X)^{-1}$

$(X^T X)^{-1}X^T X\beta=(X^T X)^{-1}X^Ty$

$(X^T X)^{-1}X^T X= I$ (Identity matrix).

Finally you get $\beta=(X^T X)^{-1}X^Ty$

**Equality of** $\beta ^T \mathbf{X} ^Ty$ and $y^TX\beta$

I make an example:

$\left( \begin{array}{c c} b_1 & b_2 \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c c c} x_{11} & x_{21} \\ x_{12} & x_{22}\end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c c} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{array} \right) $

$=\left( \begin{array}{c c} b_1x_{11}+b_2x_{12} & b_1x_{21}+b_2x_{22} \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c c} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{array} \right)$

$=b_1 x_{11}y_1+b_2 x_{12}y_1+b_1x_{21}y_2+b_2x_{22}y_2\quad (\color{blue}{I})$

---

$\left( \begin{array}{c c} y_1 & y_2 \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c c c} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22}\end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c c} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{array} \right) $

$=\left( \begin{array}{c c} y_1x_{11}+y_2x_{21} & y_1x_{12}+y_2x_{22} \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c c} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{array} \right)$

$=y_1 x_{11}b_1+y_2 x_{21}b_1+y_1x_{12}b_2+y_2x_{22}b_2 \quad (\color{blue}{II})$

$\color{blue}{I}$ and $\color{blue}{II}$ are equal.

**Derivative Rules**

$\frac{\partial \beta ^T X ^T y }{\partial \beta  }=X^Ty$

$\frac{\partial \beta^T X^T X \beta }{\partial \beta }=2X^TX\beta$

Comment: I understand that $X^T\beta^T y$ and $y^TX\beta$ are just transposes of each other. Why are they equal? (Are transposes of each other always equal?)

Comment: @cgo $\beta ^T \mathbf{X} ^Ty$ and $y^TX\beta$ are the transposes of each other (I have made an edit). In general this kind of expressions are not equal. But here $\beta ^T \mathbf{X} ^Ty$ and $y^TX\beta$ are scalars. Thus they are equal.

Comment: May I know why these two terms are equal? I do not understand why.

Comment: @cgo I have made an edit. Additional I have posted the relevant derivative rules.

Answer (score 2):

$X\beta$ is a vector with $i$-th entry (using summation notation): $$(X\beta)_i=X_i\cdot\beta=X_{ij}\beta_j$$
so $(y-X\beta)_i=y_i-X_{ij}\beta_j,$
and thus $$(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)=(y_i-X_{ij}\beta_j)^2,$$
taking a derivative with respect to $\beta_k$ for each $k=1,\ldots,n$ we obtain:
$$\partial_{\beta_k}RSS=2(-X_{ik})(y_i-X_{ij}\beta_j)=-2\sum_{i,j=1}^nX_{ik}(y_i-X_{ij}\beta_j)=0,\,\,\,\,k=1,\ldots,n,$$
i.e.,
$X^k\cdot y=X^k\cdot X\beta,\,\,\,\,k=1,\ldots,n$, where $X^k$ is the $k$-th column of $X$. This is equivalent to 
$$X^Ty=X^T(X\beta),$$
so $\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. To verify what kind of critical point we have, take the $l$-th derivative of $\partial_{\beta_k}RSS$, and we have:
$$\partial^2_{\beta_k\beta_l}RSS=2\partial_{\beta_l}\sum_{i,j=1}^nX_{ik}X_{ij}\beta_j=2\sum_{i=1}^nX_{ik}X_{il}=2X^k\cdot X^l,$$
now whether or not we have a maximum/ minimum etc, depends on the nature of the matrix $X$, as we need the Hessian of $RSS$ to be a positive definite matrix for a minimum.

Comment: Its $\beta ^T X ^T X \beta$ not $X_iX_i\beta^2$

Comment: You mean $\beta X^TX\beta$ right? and these are vectors, so we get $\beta X^TX\beta=\sum_{i=1}^n\beta^2X_i^2$ where $n$ is the dimension. I have just used summation notation, i.e., summing over repeated indices.

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate without expanding the summations? Is the solution I suggested above, in any way, correct?

Comment: I'll do it in that sense with the product rule, one sec.

Comment: Is the last term supposed to be $(-\mathbf{X})$ only and not $-\mathbf{X}\beta$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry typo

Comment: @ellya In my in opinion you can´t multiply like this. $\beta $ and $\beta ^T$ are vektors with different dimensions.

Comment: @calculus I was under the impression that $\beta$ was a scalar?

Comment: @ellya No $\beta$ is a vector. The b´s are the  estimatied coefficients for the regression line.

Comment: @calculus ah this was not clear (at least to me), is $X$ a matrix then? regardless, I will remove this answer

Comment: @ellya Yes. X is a matrix. Don´t remove your answer, improve it.

Comment: I realized $\beta$ is a vector that does not depend on either $y$ or $x$. So $\beta^T$ is different from $\beta$.

Comment: I have edited now, accounting for the fact that $\beta$ is a vector

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this by differentiating.  Let $P$ be the matrix that projects orthogonally onto the column space of the design matrix $X$.  Then $y-Py$ is orthogonal to $P\mathbf y - X\beta$, since $P\mathbf y$ and $X\beta$ are both in the column space of $X$.  Then we have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{RSS}(\beta) & = (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)^T(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta) \\[8pt]
& = ((\mathbf y - P\mathbf y)+(P\mathbf y - X\beta))^T((\mathbf y - P\mathbf y)+(P\mathbf y - X\beta)) \\[8pt]
& = (\mathbf y-P\mathbf y)^T(\mathbf y-P\mathbf y) + (P\mathbf y-X\beta)^T(P\mathbf y-X\beta) \\
&\phantom{{}={}} + \underbrace{(\mathbf y-P\mathbf y)^T(P\mathbf y-X\beta) + (P\mathbf y-X\beta)^T(\mathbf y - P\mathbf y)}_{\text{This sum is zero, by orthogonality.}} \\[10pt]
& = (\mathbf y-P\mathbf y)^T(\mathbf y-P\mathbf y) + (P\mathbf y-X\beta)^T(P\mathbf y-X\beta).
\end{align}
Now $\beta$ appears only in the second term.  The second term can be minimized by making it $0$ since $P\mathbb y$ is in the column space of $X$ and therefore $\beta$ can be so chosen as to make $X\beta=P\mathbf y$.

The matrix $X$ has typically far more rows than columns.  If the columns of $X$ are linearly independent, then $X$ has an **left**-inverse, which is $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.  Invertibility of $X^TX$ follows from linear independence of the columns of $X$.

Hence the equation $X\beta=P\mathbf y$ can be solved for $\beta$ by multiplying both sides on the left by that left-inverse.

Comment: May I know why you would not differentiate this? Is it just a preference?

Comment: Because this stuff involving orthogonal projections is frequently used in problems like this in statistics, this problem being probably by far the simplest one you'll ever see.  There's no reason to make a freak exception out of this one simplest example. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I've forgotten an immense amount about this sort of thing, but these techniques is used in (1) design of experiments and (2) problems in multivariate statistics involving Wishart distributions.  Kronecker products are heavily relied upon in both areas, at least in the way I've seen them done.

Comment: I should add that $P=X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T$.  A very "pure" mathematician (whose name would be recognized by many here) once glanced at that and said it's the identity matrix.  So it is _if_ $X$ is a square matrix, but in general it is a matrix of rank only as big as the number of columns of $X$.  Based on this I formed a hypothesis: "purity" as opposed to "appliedness" is correlated with assuming that matrices are square --- have just as many rows as columns. ${}\qquad{}$